# Cannot bulk upload triples to virtuoso graph using the bulk upload functions

Tags: transactions, rdf, graph-databases, virtuoso, bulk-load

I am trying to upload triples to Virtuoso with the bulk upload function(s) mentioned here: https://github.com/dbpedia/dbpedia-docs/wiki/Loading-Data-Virtuoso. Sometimes the bulk upload is working, sometimes not.

So here is what I did (I'm working on a CentOS machine):

Downloaded / installed Virtuoso (latest version)

Started Virtuoso on port `8890` by specifying the default `virtuoso.ini` file:

```
virtuoso -f virtuoso.ini
```

Started the iSQL interpreter that comes with it:

```
./isql 1111
```

Loaded the bulk upload functions (can for instance be found here : https://github.com/mysema/rdfbean/blob/master/rdfbean-virtuoso/doc/rdfloader.sql):

```
LOAD rdfloader.sql
```

Uploaded a first triple file (~500 Mb):

```
ld_dir('/path/to/dir1','*.gz','http://graph.1.com');
rdf_loader_run();
```

(let's call that transaction 1, it worked well)

Tried to load another file to another graph

```
ld_dir('/path/to/dir2','*.gz','http://graph.2.com');
rdf_loader_run();
```

(let's call that transaction 2)

It did not work, and even though the Virtuoso log file did not point toward the source of the error, the SQL table to which transaction events are written to (`DB.DBA.LOAD_LIST`) mentioned that something was wrong with the line 16061:

```
37000 SP029: TURTLE RDF loader, line 16061: syntax error processed pending to here.
```

I corrected the file accordingly, typed into the iSQL interpreter the -almost- same command as transaction 2:

```
ld_dir('/path/to/dir2','*.gz','http://graph.3.com');
rdf_loader_run();
```

(let's call that transaction 3)

And now nothing happens. The `DB.DBA.LOAD_LIST` does not even contain that new transaction. It only contains transactions 1 and 2.

Has anyone a clue of what is going on under the hood and why nothing is happening here ?

Comment: "Latest version" may mean many things.  Please update your question with the output of `virtuoso-t -?` (changing the binary name if necessary to suit your deployment).

Comment: I see you're following a guide from the DBpedia project, but it's not clear whether you're loading DBpedia data. I suggest you try following the Virtuoso documentation, such as [Bulk Loading RDF Source Files](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtBulkRDFLoader).  Note that these bulk load features have been built into Virtuoso since 6.1.3, 2011-03-30, while the `rdfloader.sql` you manually loaded dates from 2010-12-15.

Comment: Virtuoso-specific assistance often comes faster via Virtuoso-focused resources such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a [confidential OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for future reference

When an error happens during a Bulk Upload operation, you need to clear the DB.DBA.LOAD_LIST table before proceeding.

```
private static final String clearBulkLoadTbl = "DELETE FROM DB.DBA.load_list";

private void clearBulkLoadHistory() throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement clearBulkLoadTblStmt;
    clearBulkLoadTblStmt = virt_conn.prepareStatement(clearBulkLoadTbl);                        
    clearBulkLoadTblStmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Hope it helps someone.